# Git delete some history commits to reduce .git folder size, how?

Tags: git

I come into a really tough problem.

**I have a very huge repo on my server. huge means: lots of commits, branches which result in a big .git folder.**

Now I want to drop some history commits before a date in order to reduce .git folder size.

Past week, I learn a lot about git. and I find that the more I lean , the more confused I am.

**My question is:**

1. Can it really small .git  size a lot by drop some history commits? as the older reversion file may be still used now.
2. if #1 true, how can I do this? I learn to use .git/info/grafts + git filter-branch.. but every time the result is a mess.  the commit line is splited to several lines because before where I cut off there are a lot of branches.
3. Even i solved splited lines, get a single line as i expect. but my git repo is a publish one, many people has cloned it and work on it. Can it possible for local repo to solve conflicts without re-clone remote handled repo?

I wish I made my question clear.

Any advice will be appreciated!!!

Comment: I would not use git to track data - I guess you do so. If you only use git for tracking code ("text files") the size should be rather small (MB).

Comment: @Christoph I use git to track Android code. There will be some images and libs which is much bigger than code .

Comment: What I do: Use backups for images, ... Use git for code only (and for data, where changes can(!) be tracked and where changes really need(!) to be tracked).

Answer (score 2):

I can answer #1.

I highly recommend you reduce the size of the Git repo on your remote server without deleting previous commits. This is because you may need to revert to a previous commit if someone pushing a commit to your Git repo makes an error.

**To reduce the size of your Git repo on your remote server:**

1. Navigate to your Git repo in your shell (command line tool).
2. Type in the commands below in your shell, pressing **Enter** on your keyboard after each line. **These commands will remove any references to deleted Git branches and reduce your Git repo size.**

git reflog expire --all --expire=now

git gc --prune=now --aggressive

Comment: yes,using these commands may reduce size a little. but not too much.that is not what i want

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to just reset to limit the number of commits you have. Or git revert if you want to do it more safely:

git reset

Take a look at https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-reset; Except where otherwise noted, all content is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 Australia License.

Comment: I just want to drop some history commits and keep my recent commits unchanged. git reset is not what i want .

Answer (score -1):

The command **git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f ' HEAD** should help you with the requieed.